# Dice probability of exact number of heads

Tags: probability

A friend of mine posed a problem that $200$ coins are tossed at once and assuming the coins are fair, find the probability of getting exactly $17$ heads.

**My approach:**

We simply use the probability generating function of binomial distribution.

Denote by $h$ the event of getting a head. Then, we have,

$$P(h=17): \binom{200}{17}\frac{1}{2^{200}}$$

Calculating this gives us our answer.

---

The answer comes out to be approximately $1.139\times 10^{-36}$ as seen here: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28\binom{200}{17}%29%2F2^{200}.

My friend says that this isn't the answer. I'm confused. Did I miss anything?

**Notice:** Please don't answer this question. I simply want comments on this post to tell me if there's something wrong with my approach. I don't even want any hints since I want to get it by myself.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your approach.  This is a classic example of Binomial Probability.  Note, he might be expecting to see the answer as $\binom{200}{17}(\frac{1}{2})^{17}(\frac{1}{2})^{183}$, but that is exactly the same as yours, assuming that its not a trick question in some way (that some coins are doubleheads) or that you misinterpreted his question and it should have been "at least 17 heads" or some other related question.

Comment: I think -in fact, I'm pretty sure- that your answer is correct.

Comment: @JMoravitz, actually, he wants the answer in the form $a\times 10^{-b}$ where $b$ is less than $7$. That'd make $a$ a very large number which doesn't agree with his thinking. I'm weak at combinatorics, so I'm scratching my head over and over again thinking I might be wrong.

Comment: The only thing wrong I would say, is your notation.  $P(h=17)$ doesn't make sense, since you defined "h" as "*the event of getting a head*."  You should have defined a random variable to be $X=$ *the total number of heads* in which case $P(X=17)$ is exactly what you say it is.

Comment: @JMoravitz, did I tell you that I'm bad with probability notations? :P That's a mistake, I admit. I wrote it hastily, so... :P

Comment: Then, my answer is correct?

Comment: Yes, your answer is correct.  If he disagrees, then refer him to the [wiki page on binomial distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) and note that this is binomially distributed with $n=200, p=\frac{1}{2}, q=\frac{1}{2}$ and the result follows immediately.

Comment: Yay! So, there's nothing wrong with me! :P Thanks, @JMoravitz

Comment: Are you sure it's $200$?  Maybe you flip $20$ coins?

Comment: @BrianTung, Nope, it's 200.

Comment: Your friend should realize it's not unreasonable for it to be very much smaller than 10^-7. If the coin is fair and you're flipping it 200 times, and getting only 17 heads, that is an extremely unlikely scenario, isn't it? you would expect somewhere around half to be heads

Comment: @TBrendle, exactly my thought at first! Anyway, thanks for the help, guys!

Comment: probdude: Yeah, well, it was a long shot.  TBrendle: $10^{-7}$ is a very small number to civilians. :-)